# .emacs file (script) doesn't work

Tags: emacs, macros, emacs23

I've just installed new distribution of Ubuntu 10.10.2010, then installed emacs23, I installed also emacs goodies for color themes.

I made the file .emacs in my home directory with the code:

```
(require 'color-theme)
   (setq color-theme-is-global t)
   (color-theme-euphoria)
```

but it doesn't work, with any code even `(setq inhibit-startup-message   t)`
I made a new file named  .emacs.el but nothing. There is a folder with the name ".emacs.d" generated by the installation. I even tried putting emacs file in it, still nothing.

now I think any startup script won't work. so what should I do to know why Emacs doesn't read that file ?

---

Update: I deleted all the mess files and left the ~/.emacs.el file and now the code is :

```
(setq inhibit-startup-message   t)
(require 'color-theme)
(setq color-theme-is-global   t)
(color-theme-euphoria)
```

but gives error: Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/marmoush/.emacs.el': Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-euphoria

Comment: Do you get an error on emacs startup?

Comment: if you load .emacs once emacs is running. does it work?

Comment: yes now after i deleted all files and left (.emacs.el) the error is Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/homeuser/.emacs.el':

Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-euphoria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know but when I used this code it worked !

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-robin-hood)
```

Comment: If you'd read the quickstart guide, you'd see that you were missing the call to `color-theme-initialize` (which you have in this answer).   http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/#sec8

Comment: @Trey Jackson, I've read a good reference which had both scripts, first one was the one which was actually working 10 months ago, then i moved to IDE's later when I returned to using emacs, I tried the one which was working, and did some search, and thought of trying the second :D ! but I didn't pay much attention to what's in the script (initialize thing) back then

Answer (score 2):

Weird. Try saving it as ~/.emacs.d/init.el

Comment: I recommend this. Putting all your settings in a single folder makes things more logical, and you aren't tempted to throw everything in a single setup file. The directory plays well with version control systems, and lastly your setup file isn't (as) hidden.

Answer (score 1):

First, delete your `.emacs` file. When Emacs starts up, customize some values using the menu and save them. A new `.emacs` file should be created somewhere. Find out where, and then edit it as you please.

Comment: Go to Options -> Customize Emacs -> Browse customization groups. Change some settings and choose "Save for future sessions".